# Receber mensagens IRC CLIENT VB

Tags: visual-basic-6

Ola, estou com uma dificuldade para receber as mensagens de uma conexão IRC feita em VB,
Aqui o Codigo:
[image: Conexão com a irc VB]
Ja foi adicionado a biblioteca como referencia IrcClient.dll.
Esta falando que o irc_ChannelMessage não pode manipular o evento, peocurei a respeito mas não tive sucesso.
[image: Erro]

Aqui esta o Projeto com o metodo "*sender As Object, e As ChannelMessageEventArgs*"

Porém ao chamar "Message" não reconhece como sendo do IRC
[image: sender As Object, e As ChannelMessageEventArgs]

> Dim WithEvents irc As IrcClient
>
> Public Sub Conectar()
>   irc = New IrcClient("chat.freenode.net:6665")
>   irc.Nick = txtNick.Text
>   irc.JoinChannel("##C++")
>   irc.Connect()
>   lblStatos.Text = "Conectado Servidor Irc."
>   End Sub
>
> Public Sub ircChannelMessage(sender As Object, e As ChannelMessageEventArgs) Handles irc.ChannelMessage
>   txtMensagens.AppendText(Message & vbNewLine)
>   txtMensagens.ScrollToCaret()
>   lblMensagens.Text = "Lendo Mensagens."
>   End Sub

https://github.com/MrDeppy/deppy

Answer (score 0):

Os parâmetros do método `irc_ChannelMessage` não estão corretos.

Pela mensagem de erro, parece que o correto seria colocar a seguinte assinatura:

```
Private Sub irc_ChannelMessage(sender As Object, e As ChannelMessageEventArgs) Handles irc.ChannelMessage
End Sub
```

Comment: A mensagem de erro desapareceu, porém não consigo chamar as respostas do servidor. 
Vou enviar o projeto.

Comment: Aqui esta o projeto

https://github.com/MrDeppy/deppy

Fiz a correção, porém não consigo chamar a "Message" para a TextBox.
preciso receber as resposta do servidor.